# Get width and height of image at run time - WP8

Tags: c#, image, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am working on Windows Phone 8 app.

I have a path to image - `/Data/Images/image1.png`. I am able to display this image on screen, but i want to change the width and height of the image before its rendered.

This is how i am displaying the image in `webbrowser control`

```
webbrowser.Append("<img src=""+path+ width=\"250\" height=\"250\" style=\"vertical-align:middle\" alt=\"\"></img>"/>"
```

Here i am setting width and height as `250x250` but i want to change that height and width as some images are not looking good.

Comment: Could you use the `Image.FromFile` function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx), then do something like this: `Image i = Image.FromFile("/Data/Images/image1.png"); webbrowser.Append("<img src=""+path+ width=\"" + i.Width + "\" height=\"" + i.Height + "\" style=\"vertical-align:middle\" alt=\"\"></img>"/>");` ... ?

Comment: @txtechhelp Its gives me error that `System.Windows.Controls.Image Image.FromFile` could not be found

Comment: @txtechhelp see this `there is no system.drawing in WP8`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385642/convert-image-to-byte-array-on-windows-phone-7-no-system-drawing-dll-any-other-w

Comment: What version of the framework are you using?

Comment: @txtechhelp I am new to WP8, so how to check that?

Comment: Apparently you're stuck with importing the .NET `System.Drawing` dll if you wish to use that namespace in WP; for your question however @OlivierPayen provides a nice solution.

Comment: @txtechhelp any idea how i can disable only horizontall scroll for Webbrowser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the get the size of an image, you need to load it in a `BitmapImage`:

```
int width = 0;
int height = 0;
using (var stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/test.jpg", UriKind.Relative)).Stream)
{
    var bmpi = new BitmapImage();
    bmpi.SetSource(stream);
    bmpi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
    width = bmpi.PixelWidth;
    height = bmpi.PixelHeight;
    bmpi = null; // Avoids memory leaks
}
```

Comment: one more question How can we disable `only horizontall scroll to webrowser control ?` so that it fits to the width and height of device

Comment: can you please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566872/webbrowser-control-with-transparent-background