# How to convert an image to byte array in windows phone 8.1 using c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am using this code

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(myimage);
wb.SaveJpeg(ms, myimage.PixelWidth, myimage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
byte [] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
```

from [Convert image to byte array on Windows Phone 7 No System.Drawing Dll any other way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385642/convert-image-to-byte-array-on-windows-phone-7-no-system-drawing-dll-any-other-w) but WriteableBitmap does not contain SaveJpeg method in Windows phone 8.1 environment.

Comment: There must be something that causing you to think that it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you targeting Silverlight or Runtime - depending on this there are different methods to save bitmap.

Answer (score 3):

On *Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight applications* your code works fine, I assume that `myImage` is a `BitmapImage`. The only thing just must do is to wait for the `BitmapImage` to load completly:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
...
myImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://i.stack.imgur.com/830Ke.jpg?s=128&g=1", UriKind.Absolute));
myImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
myImage.ImageOpened += myImage_ImageOpened;
...
void myImage_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(myImage);
    wb.SaveJpeg(ms, myImage.PixelWidth, myImage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```

I just tested that code and it works perfectly on WP8.1.

But as you commented on another post you can't reference `Microsoft.Phone`, you are probably doing a Windows Phone 8.1 Store App, in which case you can use the following code:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
...
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://i.stack.imgur.com/830Ke.jpg?s=128&g=1"));
RandomAccessStreamReference rasr = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(bitmapImage.UriSource);
var streamWithContent = await rasr.OpenReadAsync();
byte[] buffer = new byte[streamWithContent.Size];
await streamWithContent.ReadAsync(buffer.AsBuffer(), (uint)streamWithContent.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are targeting [Windows Runtime Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn642041.aspx) as you haven't found [the namespace suggested in this answer (which will work for WP8.1 Silverlight)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23801184/2681948).

In Windows Runtime apps you can use `Encoder` - the sample code can look like this:

```
// lets assume that you have your image in WriteableBitmap yourWb
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, ms.AsRandomAccessStream());
    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
        BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
        imageWidth,
        imageHeight,
        horizontalDPI,
        verticalDPI,
        yourWb.PixelBuffer.ToArray());

    await encoder.FlushAsync();
}
```

Comment: thanks @Romasz to your reply. I resolved my problem another way.

Comment: @ababil If I may ask - how? Maybe you can add yourself an answer?

Comment: Sure @Romasz. My colplete code:
XAML:
 <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnSubmit" Content="Submit" Click="btnSubmit_Click"/>
        <Image Grid.Row="2" x:Name="imagePreivew" />

Comment: BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/ImYzXmXzbrWHt5wsrRkN_53OWH9nP6y_jqvH3nbXIQ=s207-p-no?s=128&g=1"));
            RandomAccessStreamReference rasr = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(bitmapImage.UriSource);
            var streamWithContent = await rasr.OpenReadAsync();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[streamWithContent.Size];
            await streamWithContent.ReadAsync(buffer.AsBuffer(), (uint)streamWithContent.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);

Comment: @Romasz There is no explanation for how to set image data to writeable bitmap. Youre creating writeable bitmap with image width and height. And there is no data in 'yourWb.pixelbuffer'.

Comment: @MohanRajNK Yeah, you are right, but this was just an example to show the right direction. If you are looking how to get pixelbuffer, you may take a look [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25995145/2681948).

Answer (score 0):

SaveJpeg is an extension method ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions.savejpeg(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions.savejpeg%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)).   Have you referenced `Microsoft.Phone` in your project references and added `using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;` to your .cs file?

Comment: thanks for quick reply @tster. I have not found Microsoft.Phone reference as you mentioned.Do you suggest me how to achieve this another way.

Comment: @ababil, Try creating a "Windows Phone" project in Visual Studio.  That will come with Microsoft.Phone referenced.

Comment: Microsoft.Phone namespace no longer exists in Windows Phone 8.1 platform.