# How to convert Bitmap image to byte array in wp7?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
    image.UriSource = new Uri("/Images/chef.png", UriKind.Relative);              

    WriteableBitmap LoadedPhoto = new WriteableBitmap(image);
    LoadedPhoto.SaveJpeg(ms, LoadedPhoto.PixelWidth, LoadedPhoto.PixelHeight,0,95);
    ms.Seek(0, 0);
    byte[] data = new byte[ms.Length];
    ms.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    ms.Close();
 }
```

I am getting NullReferenceException at image, but my path is also correct and image also exists.

```
WriteableBitmap LoadedPhoto = new WriteableBitmap(image);
```

Is anything goes wrong.

Comment: I don't see the line `BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage()` or anything similar?

Comment: Please Refer this solution first,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732807/conversion-of-bitmapimage-to-byte-array

Comment: are you getting your solution or yet not?

Comment: Where do you create the image object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Refer the solution.
which shows the solution to converting the bitmapimages to byte array.

I hope you will understand..
[conversion of bitmapimage to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732807/conversion-of-bitmapimage-to-byte-array)

Refer this link..

Comment: Thanks...but now I am getting UnauthorisedException.