# Store BitmapImage in a text file (and back again)

Tags: c#, encoding, bitmap, arrays

I have a [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) and I need to store the content of this image (as byte array for example) in a text file.

In particular, I have to store this image in the attribute of an XML node, and then I have to read this node to create a new `BitmapImage`.

What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: This is not WPF related, removing tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Convert's [ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) to covert Bytes to readable ASCII characters

```
string bitmapImageAsString=Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData);
```

You can convert that string back using [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

---

To convert BitmapImage to byte array refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732807/conversion-of-bitmapimage-to-byte-array)..

Though you can also use [BitmapImage.StreamSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx) to identify the source stream and then convert that stream to byte array..That would be a better option

Comment: To convert my `StreamSource` to a byte array I'm using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7073124/995246) method. But I think it's a huge waste of resources... Do you know a better way?

Comment: @gliderkite performance won't be a problem here but if you want your code to copy that stream without **blocking** you can use [CopyToAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159084.aspx)