# Upload() request not working with Google Drive API in windows phone 8 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone, google-drive-api

I create a simple page for this. a "choose" `button`, an "upload" `button` and an `displayImage` control to display the images after choosing from `PhotoChooserTask`. And below is my whole class:

```
    PhotoChooserTask photoChooserTask;
    BitmapImage bmi;
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void chooseBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
        photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);
        photoChooserTask.Show();
    }

    private void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        bmi = new BitmapImage();
        bmi.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        displayImage.Source = bmi;
    }

    private async void uploadBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                             DriveService.Scope.DriveFile};
        ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets()
        {
            ClientId = "MY CLIENT ID",
            ClientSecret = "MY SECRET"
        };

        var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets,
            scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None);

        var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Assignment 1",
        };
        //The authorization works!

        var service = new DriveService(initializer);

        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
        body.Title = "My document";
        body.Description = "A test document";
        body.MimeType = "image/jpeg";


        byte[] byteArray = this.ConvertToBytes(bmi);
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "image/jpeg");
        MessageBox.Show("The code reached here"); // The app shows this message. But can't move to the Upload() line.
        request.Upload();
        MessageBox.Show("Upload completed!");


    }


    //The codes below is copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732807/conversion-of-bitmapimage-to-byte-array
    public byte[] ConvertToBytes(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WriteableBitmap btmMap = new WriteableBitmap
                (bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight);

            Extensions.SaveJpeg(btmMap, ms,
                bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

After authorizing, nothing happens after showing `MessageBox.Show("The code reached here");` with no error just like it's done its job. But actually the image has not been uploaded yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution for this which is very simple but got me about a month to figure it out.

It's not `request.Upload();`, it's`request.UploadAsync();` as my method use async.

And `ConvertToBytes` method above is wrong, I uploaded a black image. But I tried another method which gets a string of path as an argument ( `ReadImageFile("myimage.jpg");` works)

```
    public static byte[] ReadImageFile(string imageLocation)
    {
        byte[] imageData = null;
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(imageLocation);
        long imageFileLength = fileInfo.Length;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(imageLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        imageData = br.ReadBytes((int)imageFileLength);
        return imageData;
    }
```

The next things I'm gonna do is to get the path of my BitmapImage to use the method or just find another byte[] method that works.

Hope it helps someone.